# Published Web App Getting AADSTS50011 Error

Tags: asp.net, azure-active-directory

Trying to fix this Azure Active Directory issue.  I have an ASP.Net 4.7 website.  It correctly takes me to the SSO page and confirms my identity.  However, upon taking me back to my site, I get the message:

> *AADSTS50011: The reply URL specified in the request does not match the reply URLs configured for the application: 'MyApplication-ClientID'.*

It makes sense that the AD App Registration's | Authentication | Redirect URI does not match what I am sending it.  However, as near as I can tell, they do.

Here is my code in the `Startup.cs` file:

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app) {
    app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
    app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
        new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions {
            ClientId = clientId,       // MyApplication-ClientID
            Authority = authority,     // https://login.microsoftonline.com/MyDirectory-TenantID/v2.0
            RedirectUri = redirectUri, // https://MySiteName.azurewebsites.net
            PostLogoutRedirectUri = redirectUri,
            Scope = OpenIdConnectScope.OpenIdProfile,
            ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.IdToken,
            TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters() {
                ValidateIssuer = false
            },
            Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications {
                AuthenticationFailed = OnAuthenticationFailed
            }
        }
    );
}
```

Here are the settings in my `Web.config` file:

```
<add key="ClientId" value="MyApplication-ClientID" />
<add key="Tenant" value="common" />
<add key="Authority" value="https://login.microsoftonline.com/MyDirectory-TenantID/v2.0" />
<add key="RedirectUri" value="https://MySiteName.azurewebsites.net" />
```

Both the Redirect URI and the Configs RedirectUri are: `https://MySiteName.azurewebsites.net`

Here is the initial request when I am asked to select an account when trying to log in:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/MyDirectory-TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
    ?response_type=code+id_token
    &redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2FMySiteName.azurewebsites.net%2F.auth%2Flogin%2Faad%2Fcallback
    &client_id=MyApplication-ClientID
    &scope=openid+profile+email
    &response_mode=form_post
    &nonce=3f63a75d79af449082801c5183d5fbdb_20200710145808
    &state=redir%3D%252F
```

So I see the `redirect_uri` seems to add the `/.auth/login/aad/callback` to the end of what I told it to be.  So I updated the AD App Registration's | Authentication | Redirect URI to match and instead of the above error I get the following error:

> *The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.*

I am just at a loss here trying to figure out what is mismatched or perhaps just missing.

Comment: It seems to be an server error. Are you sure the service is running fine?

Comment: Yes, I am sure.  I would agree with your comment when I alter the url (thus the 2nd error message) - but the primary error message would not indicate any service being down.

Comment: Can you share a fiddler of the entire flow?

I would say that the error message now is on the application side. We are sending the response back with the token to the /.auth/login/aad/callback endpoint on your application. Is your application prepared to receive these responses on this endpoint?

Comment: @Nishant-MSFTIdentity I have gotten further with this but now I have a new issue.  It seems closer but now in a loop. Can you please check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63140000/373438) out, there is some fiddler data.  I can give you more, just need to know what.